# How to setup an autocommand for the preview window's buffer?

Tags: vim

How do I setup an autocommand to trigger for the preview window's buffer solely? I have one that works on the quickfix window because its filetype is `qf`, so I can setup a FileType autocommand for it. I've checked quickfix window's buffer FileType but it's empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no explicit event, but you can easily check for the preview window via the `'previewwindow'` option, and combine that with another event, e.g. `WinEnter`:

```
:autocmd WinEnter * if &previewwindow | ... | endif
```

Comment: Is there also a way to detect the preview buffer without window events or checking for window attributes?

Comment: @Arne The event gets your code triggered and the attribute tests the window; that's how Vim's API works. Why would you want to use a different way?

Comment: I am asking because this is a *window* event, so when I am entering the *window*. The point is, I don't want to enter the window. I want to set the buffer of the previewwindow as not listed, before it enter it with `:bn`.So I want it to be triggered on a BufCreate event, and my focus is explicity not the previewwindow.

Comment: @Arne: According to my tests, you can even check `&previewwindow` on `BufAdd`. This works with `:pedit`, which doesn't focus the window.

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer didn't solve the problem for me because it only triggered when the preview window was *entered*, not when it was created.

Thanks to [this vim tip](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Detect_window_creation_with_WinEnter), I found that `BufWinEnter` does fire on preview window creation.

```
autocmd! BufWinEnter * if &previewwindow | call s:previewWinSettings() | endif
```

The only times it won't fire are if using `:pedit` on an already-loaded buffer.